# How to get the contourf handler from matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, contourf

I was wondering how to get the contourf handler from an axes within matplotlib. From the codes and outputs below you can easily find that `im` is `matplotlib.contour.QuadContourSet` but no such kind of thing in `ax.get_children()`. I know I can obtain `im` by assigning operations but sometimes using `ax.get_children()` can make life much easier when I just want to use `im` in another place once.

#### Codes

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
im = ax.contourf(np.random.random((10,10)))
im, ax.get_children()
```

#### Output

```
(<matplotlib.contour.QuadContourSet at 0x2abd4a3243c8>,
 [<matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x2abd4a35b080>,
  <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x2abd4a35b4e0>,
  <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x2abd4a35ba58>,
  <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x2abd4a35be48>,
  <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x2abd4a365240>,
  <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x2abd4a365710>,
  <matplotlib.collections.PathCollection at 0x2abd4a365c18>,
  <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x2abd4a282a90>,
  <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x2abd4a282b38>,
  <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x2abd4a2f7320>,
  <matplotlib.spines.Spine at 0x2abd4a294d68>,
  <matplotlib.axis.XAxis at 0x2abd4a29a4a8>,
  <matplotlib.axis.YAxis at 0x2abd4a317748>,
  Text(0.5, 1.0, ''),
  Text(0.0, 1.0, ''),
  Text(1.0, 1.0, ''),
  <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle at 0x2abd4a33ca58>])
```

Comment: It's not possible to retrieve the `QuadContourSet` object back from the axes. All the axes knows about is the individual `PathCollection`s.

Comment: Hi @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for letting know!